# Failed to exec start script, openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

Starting my first app on Openshift. Had everything running perfectly well on my local PC. Can't get it going on the Openshift server. Pretty sure it's some configuration issue. Any thoughts?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.35
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart demos-cfg@0.0.1
6 info start demos-cfg@0.0.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info demos-cfg@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
9 error demos-cfg@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
9 error Exit status 8
10 error Failed at the demos-cfg@0.0.1 start script.
10 error This is most likely a problem with the demos-cfg package,
10 error not with npm itself.
10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10 error     node server.js
10 error You can get their info via:
10 error     npm owner ls demos-cfg
10 error There is likely additional logging output above.
11 error System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
12 error command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "start"
13 error cwd /var/lib/openshift/<uname>/app-root/runtime/repo
14 error node -v v0.10.35
15 error npm -v 1.4.28
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

On my local device, in my server.js file, I have:

```
app.listen('3000',function(){
console.log("<== App is started at PORT local ==>");
});
```

For Openshift, seems like I'm supposed to add:

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + port )
});
```

Comment: That is correct, on OpenShift you should retrieve the port and ip address you are allowed to use from the environment (OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP). The settings after the '||' are the ones you can use on your local system, so if you prefer to use port 3000, you can change the 8080 to whatever you prefer.

Comment: seemed like using the Openshift version, but changing "server.listen" to "app.listen" worked